# Android: get result from callback (networking KOUSH ION)

Tags: android, android-asynctask, callback, future

For my app I need to contact our API from our server which returns some JSON.

While downloading the JSON, it should display a progressbar.

I figured I should use Android's `AsyncTask` to handle the GUI while doing network operations, so I wrote the following within my `Activity`:

```
 class DownloadManager extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mLoadingSpinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        String id = params[0];
        downloadUtility.getId(id);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        mLoadingSpinner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    }

}
```

Basically, `onPreExecute` shows the loading spinner, the `doInBackGround` downloads some JSON, and `onPostExecute` stops the spinner.

The question is, within the `downloadUtility.getId(id)` I need to either:

1. Open a new intent if the download **succeeded**.
2. Stay on the same activity and display an error toast if the download **failed**.

The code for the `getId`:

```
public Future getId(final String id) {
    // set url
    String url = IPAddress.PRODUCTION + Variables.get_id+ id;
    downloading = Ion.with(context)
            .load("GET", url)
            .asJsonObject()
            .withResponse()
            .setCallback(new FutureCallback<Response<JsonObject>>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Exception e, Response<JsonObject> response) {
                    //try catch here for null getHeaders
                    if (response != null) {
                        if (response.getHeaders().code() == 200) {

                            //SUCCESS !! Open new intent!


                        } else {
                            //FAIL!! Show TOAST!
                        }
                    }

                }
            });


    return downloading;

}
```

As you can see, I'm returning a future object. How do I know from the future object if the `onCompleted` (void) either gave a success or fail, so I can handle the result (success: open new intent, fail: toast) in the asynctask?

Answer (score 8):

Here you are running one asynctask inside another asyctask this is not a proper way you can call your getId method directly in your activity it won't be required another asynctask because the following code it self a asynctask.

```
 downloading = Ion.with(context)
        .load("GET", url)
        .asJsonObject()
        .withResponse()
        .setCallback(new FutureCallback<Response<JsonObject>>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Exception e, Response<JsonObject> response) {
                //try catch here for null getHeaders
                if (response != null) {
                    if (response.getHeaders().code() == 200) {

                        //SUCCESS !! Open new intent!


                    } else {
                        //FAIL!! Show TOAST!
                    }
                }

            }
        });
```

//Add new Answer

If you want to separate entire download code from your activity then you can create custom callBack in your download Utility class. It will acts like a communicator between activity and your Download class. I just give a way to do this task on bellow.

**DownloadUtility** class seams look like bellow

```
public class DownloadUtility {


//DO Your all other Stuff

/**
 * Custom Callback
 */
public interface customCallBack {
    void onCompleted(Exception e, Response<JsonObject> response);
}


/**
 * Your getID code 
 * 
 * @param context
 * @param id
 * @param mLoadingSpinner
 * @param callBack
 */
public static void getId(Activity context,final String id, Spinner mLoadingSpinner, final customCallBack callBack) {
    // set url
    mLoadingSpinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    String url = IPAddress.PRODUCTION + Variables.get_id + id;
    downloading = Ion.with(context)
            .load("GET", url)
            .asJsonObject()
            .withResponse()
            .setCallback(new FutureCallback<Response<JsonObject>>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Exception e, Response<JsonObject> response) {
                    mLoadingSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                   if(callBack != null)
                    callBack.onCompleted(e,response);
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

}

make a call on your **Activity**

```
DownloadUtility.getId(this, "ID", spinnerObj, new DownloadUtility.customCallBack() {
@Override
public void onCompleted(Exception e, Response<JsonObject> response) {
    if (response != null) {
        if (response.getHeaders().code() == 200) {
            //SUCCESS !! Open new intent!
        } else {
            //FAIL!! Show TOAST!
        }
}
```

});

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that you'd write download code within an Activity class? The reason I made a DownloadUtility class is to get rid of the entire fact to put download code within an activity, and put it in a class where it belongs.

Comment: I made some changes in answer as per your requirement, i hop it may help's you.

Comment: In above code you don't want to pass mLoadingSpinnerObject, you can start it in activity itself, you can start it before calling that function and onComplete you can stop.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that you need AsyncTask for network operation because your ion library is already using asynctask internally. 
you can do like this

```
mLoadingSpinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
downloading = Ion.with(context)
            .load("GET", url)
            .asJsonObject()
            .withResponse()
            .setCallback(new FutureCallback<Response<JsonObject>>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Exception e, Response<JsonObject> response) {
                    //try catch here for null getHeaders
                    if (response != null) {
                        if (response.getHeaders().code() == 200) {

                            //SUCCESS !! Open new intent!
                            mLoadingSpinner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        } else {
                            mLoadingSpinner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }
                    }

                }
            });
    return downloading;
```

let me know if some issue.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that you'd write download code within an Activity class? The reason I made a DownloadUtility class is to get rid of the entire fact to put download code within an activity, and put it in a class where it belongs.

Comment: yeah make a separate class and in a function add this code so you can make it separate

Comment: If I'd make a separate class, I wouldn't be able to call the mLoadingSpinner since the class isn't an activity. I could pass the loadingspinner into the constructor of the downloadUtility object, but that wouldn't be the best way. (I once tried this).

Also, for opening a new intent from a non activity, i'd have to use a FLAG to open a new activity from a normal class.. which is not nice code

Comment: inner class of your activity

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the cleanest solution is to create a service that handles the dirty download logic and returns a future of your custom response class, that contains the success info and the json object.

```
// in e.g JsonResponse.java
public class JsonResponse() {
    public boolean ok;
    public JsonObject json;
}

// in Service.java
public Future<JsonResponse> getId(final String id) {
    final SimpleFuture<JsonResponse> jsonFuture = new SimpleFuture<>();

    String url = IPAddress.PRODUCTION + Variables.get_id + id;
    Ion.with(context)
    .load("GET", url)
    .asJsonObject()
    .withResponse()
    .setCallback(new FutureCallback<Response<JsonObject>>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Exception e, Response<JsonObject> response) {
            JsonResponse jsonResponse = new JsonResponse();
            if (response != null) {
                if (response.getHeaders().code() != 200) {
                    jsonResponse.ok = false;
                } else {
                    jsonResponse.ok = true;
                    jsonResponse.json = response.getResult();   
                }
            }
            jsonFuture.setComplete(jsonResponse);
        }
    });

    return jsonFuture;
}


// in Activity.java
private void loadUser(String userId) {    
    mLoadingSpinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    service.getId(userId)
    .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonResponse>() {

        // onCompleted is executed on ui thread
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonResponse jsonResponse) {
            mLoadingSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (jsonResponse.ok) {
                // Show intent using info from jsonResponse.json
            } else {
                // Show error toast
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I did not test the code, I hope there are no big mistkases :)