# How can i return global variable from ion?

Tags: java, android, android-ion

I have some problems with getting data from ion.
I need to get variable from function and i know that this function ion  is performed separately from the main stream. 
How can i get this data? Maybe i need to wait while function doesn't completed, but how can i do it?

```
final String someText;
    Ion.with(this)
           .load(URL)
            .asString()
            .setCallback(new FutureCallback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Exception e, String result) {
                    someText = result.toString();
                    System.out.println(someText) // i get someText not empty
                }
            });
System.out.println(someText) // i get someText empty
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android: get result from callback (networking KOUSH ION)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34265401/android-get-result-from-callback-networking-koush-ion)

Comment: You are printing before the `callback` has been fired.

Comment: @scary-wombat I know it, i dont know how can i get this by used other method

Answer (score 0):

Ion is asynchronous, so someText has not been set by the callback. If you need to block to wait for the result, you can call .get() instead of using setCallback.

```
final String someText = Ion.with(this)
       .load(URL)
        .asString()
        .get(); // THIS WILL BLOCK THE THREAD
System.out.println(someText) // i get someText not empty
```

I'd not recommend doing that, because then you would block the calling thread, which may be the main thread. Using setCallback is preferred.